# How can i sort a medal table array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm working for a school project and i need to sort a multidimensional array using Kotlin. The array contains arrays of medals. I need to sort it like a medal table, where depending on the medal weight and medals count.

The array is something like this:

[0] -> [0,0,0,0,0] (for each index there is an array of 5 medals, each medal has a weight from 0 to 4, 0 is the is the least important, 4 is the most.

Example of populated array:

```
[0] -> [0,17,0,0,2]
[1] -> [1,0,0,0,0]
[2] -> [0,12,39,21,0]
[3] -> [0,13,0,11,17]
```

I need something like this:

```
[1] -> [1,0,0,0,0]
[0] -> [0,17,0,0,2]
[3] -> [0,13,0,11,17]
[2] -> [0,12,39,21,0]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: plz let us know what you have tried and the issues you are facing

Comment: Im not facing any issue, as mentioned in the title is a simple question because I don't know how to do that. What I tried is using nested for loops, but using kotlin I know there are more useful and clear ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sortedArrayWith` that takes a `Comparator`

Multiple options.

```
val medals = arrayOf(
    arrayOf(0,17,0,0,2), 
    arrayOf(1,0,0,0,0), 
    arrayOf(0,12,39,21,0), 
    arrayOf(0,13,0,11,17)
)

val sorted = medals.sortedArrayWith { a1, a2 ->
    a1.zip(a2)
        .find { it.first != it.second }
        ?.let { it.second - it.first } ?: 0
}
```

or

```
val sorted = medals.sortedArrayWith { a1, a2 ->
   a1.zip(a2).forEach {
        if(it.first != it.second) return@sortedArrayWith it.second-it.first
    }
    0
}
```

Idea is to find the first pair/index where the counts don't match, and return the maximum value.

The solution is generic that would work with any size of nested array

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to sort by the first, then the second, then the third, etc. element, and that in descending order:

```
val list = arrayOf(
  arrayOf(0, 17, 0, 0, 2),
  arrayOf(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  arrayOf(0, 12, 39, 21, 0),
  arrayOf(0, 13, 0, 11, 17)
)

val result = list
  .sortedArrayWith(
    compareByDescending<Array<Int>> { it[0] }
      .thenByDescending { it[1] }
      .thenByDescending { it[2] }
      .thenByDescending { it[3] }
      .thenByDescending { it[4] }
  )

result.forEach { println(it.toList()) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another quick general one, not necessarily the most efficient!

```
// basically sorting in reverse order, so each pass allows a group
// to move to a 'better' position
val sorted = medalGroups.apply {
    // assuming they all have the same number of indices
    // you could check with require(all { it.size == first().size }) or something
    for (i in first().indices.reversed()) {
        sortByDescending { it[i] }
    }
}
```

Or to work off lukas.j's answer (which is better) if you want to avoid repetition:

```
val sorted = medalGroups.sortedArrayWith(
    // start with the basic index 0 comparator, and tack one on for every other index
    (1 until list.size).fold(compareByDescending { it[0] }) { comparator, i ->
        comparator.thenByDescending { it[i] }
    }
)
```

You could use a `for` loop instead but folds are cool